# Create pandas DataFrame with more than one column using "data" parameter with lists as input

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem I couldn't figure out for weeks now but it sounds so simple that i cannot imagine that it's not possible.
Assuming that I have data which should be represented in columns, minimum 2 or more.
I know there are many ways to create the df and the easiest would be create a dict like

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'col1' : ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        'col2' : ['d', 'e', 'f'],
        'col3' : [1, 2, 3],
    })
```

but I would like to create it with the syntax:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data="here the lists which represent columns", index='...', columns=['...'])
```

If I have one single list of values as data with index=list('ABCD') and columns=['col1'] it works. The list of data will be a column in the DataFrame with the shape df.shape=(4,1)

If data parameter looks like this:

```
data = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
```

the output will be a df with shape (3,2) because every list will be interpreted as row where 1st row is "a" and "d" and so on, or if `index=list('ABC') and columns=[['col1','col2']]` will be added then I get the ValueError that "2 columns passed, passed data had 3 columns"

A little workaround would be:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']], index=['col1', 'col2'])
df = df.T
```

Is there a way I didn't think of? Change the input of "data" from list to Series or np.array also didn't help for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The question is: is it possible to make pandas see my data as column without using a dictionary

```
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(*data), columns=['col1', 'col2'])
print(df)

# Output
  col1 col2
0    a    d
1    b    e
2    c    f
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to pass the `dict`

```
pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(['col1','col2'],data)))
  col1 col2
0    a    d
1    b    e
2    c    f
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint with zip. Your solution is as explained in the other comment not what I am searching for, but with zip I could change my input data to row data with list comprehension: `df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[x,y] for x,y in zip([1,2,3],[4,5,6])])`

Answer (score 1):

You can assign your data to the column header like this:

```py
data = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], [1,2,3]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data={
  'col1': data[0],
  'col2': data[1],
  'col3': data[2]
})
```

Comment: which is essentially exactly the same I already described in my question. In the end both your answers ( you and @BENY ) work with creating a dictionary. Doesn't matter if created in one step and pass the variable to data or make it as oneliner or pass elements of lists of list in the dict. The question is: is it possible to make pandas see my data as column without using a dictionary